# Google Cloud Storage Transfer - Python method for getting status of TransferOperation

Tags: google-cloud-data-transfer

There does not appear to be any method in the Python client API for Google's storage transfer service that checks the status of an ongoing transfer operation. There is `get_transfer_job`, which shows the status of a transfer job itself (and gives the latest operation name). But I can't find any way of getting the status of an actual operation, which is critical.

I know other languages' client APIs (including at least Go and node.js) have this functionality. It may be possible to use a naked REST API request, but we're running into authentication issues. Is there any other way that I'm missing? Any way to call the `TransferOperation` type directly (such as `client.TransferOperation(<transfer_operation_name>)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is method available for the same which you can use in the following manner.

`GetTransferJobRequest(mapping=None, *, ignore_unknown_fields=False, **kwargs)`

Reference Link - [Class GetTransferJobRequest](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storagetransfer/latest/google.cloud.storage_transfer_v1.types.GetTransferJobRequest)

Comment: That is the request object input for a method I described in the original post, (`get_transfer_job`) and it doesn’t give details about the operation, just the job itself.